# Why are operations with cached Integers (-128 to 127) slower than with non-cached ones in this loop?

Tags: java, performance

I've got a simple program:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long sum = 0L;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            for (Integer j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
                sum++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

On my machine, this executes in about 3300 milliseconds.

When I change range for the `j` variable in the inner loop to:

`for (Integer j = 1000; j < 1100; j++)`

it executes in about 2500 milliseconds.

I would expect the second version to be executed much slower because a new `Integer` should be created in each iteration. But it is faster actually. Why?

Java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Might be because the JVM doesn't have to look up the cashed version. Also GC is probably irrelevant due to escape analysis.

Comment: The JIT optimises common use cases, and when you come up with a contrived example, which no one would do in reality it can give strange results.

Comment: JVM takes some time to check that value is in the cache. It happens for -127 - +127. For big numbers it doesn't do it and so it's faster.

Comment: You might find this [question in Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/149563/191547) relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Object creation is not a slow operation. It used to be slow in the early days of Java, and it may still be slow if you include initialization time for large, complex objects. But creating a small, single-field object is a very fast operation.
- Nevertheless, the recommendation not to create a slew of objects is still pertinent, because they waste memory. When you run out of memory, the garbage collector will run and slow down the program.
- When an integer is boxed, it runs `Integer.valueOf(int)`. The source of that method is:

  ```
  public static Integer valueOf(int i) {
      if (i >= IntegerCache.low && i <= IntegerCache.high)
          return IntegerCache.cache[i + (-IntegerCache.low)];
      return new Integer(i);
  }
  ```

  This means that for small numbers, there are:

  - two comparisons of object fields
  - negation
  - addition
  - an array lookup inside an object.

  For large numbers, there is:

  - two comparisons of an object field
  - a small object allocation
  - initialization to zero
  - an assignment of the value.

  Depending on your setup, the object allocation may be faster. On my Mac, there was very little difference between the two versions. On my Linux, I saw the same results as you described.
- It's educational to see how differently it behaves when memory is stressed.

  - Use your version with the 1000 through 1100 values.
  - You can use the same program for both cached and uncached testing: add `-Djava.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high=1500` to the java command line to have the range 1000-1100 included in the cache.
  - To test it with and without memory stress, add `-Xmx5M`

Typical results on my Linux machine (Oracle Java 1.8):

```
$ java Main
2575
1000000000

$ java -Djava.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high=1500 Main
3078
1000000000

$ java -Xmx5M Main
5812
1000000000

$ java -Xmx5M -Djava.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high=1500 Main
3102
1000000000
```

Conclusion: If you allocate many objects, it may be slightly faster when you have a lot of memory, but it will be significantly slower when you have very little and garbage collection is needed.